# Django Rest framework with Custom query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

[SOLVED]

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = articleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

I made API server using DRF.

To customize list request, I wrote views.py like this.

[views.py]

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = article.objects.all()
        serializer = articleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But, When I execute runserver, It throws error.

AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

Where is the error occured?

Comment: define `queryset = article.objects.all()` at the class level

Comment: Show your urls.py line for this

Comment: Why are you defining `list` at all here? Your version doesn't do anything special, the whole point of using a generic view or a viewset is that it does all that for you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks. Switch to class level, error was hide. But when I access to /article/, It thorws "serializer = articleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
NameError: name 'queryset' is not defined"

Comment: @AnupYadav router.register(r'article', views.articleViewSet) and then url(r'^', include(router.urls)),

Comment: try `self.queryset` ..

Comment: As Daniel said, defining serializer_class , queryset at the class level would be enough

Comment: try setting this in urls.py file need to add base_name `router.register(r'article', views.articleViewSet, base_name='article')`

Comment: @AnupYadav I fixed that issue. Thanks everyone!

Comment: How you have fixed this?

Comment: @AnupYadav I added solution. Thanks.

Comment: Which solution? If you have added mine, then it would be great you to edit your question and add urls.py line which was wrong, and I will add the answer so you can accept, so people who search get the correct answer instead of new questions

Comment: @AnupYadav I'm new at Stackoverflow. I added solution to my question. Is there more work that I have to do?

Comment: No, you need to add your problem properly at question window and if you found answer your own then add your answer using answer window / button, if you found solution from one of us, then accept that answer. And if you found mine answer useful then let me know I will add mine, you can accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
router = Router()

router.register(r'article', views.articleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)), # for django2.0.x
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)) # for django1.x
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

that's all, if you want to get all articles in list,you don't need to override list method,`ModelViewSet` will done it for you automatic.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```
class articleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = articleSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = articleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```